# Transfer weights from caffe to tensorflew

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

The convnet filter shape in caffe is **[128 64 3 3]** or **[out_dim, in_dim, filter_height, filter_weight]**. How do I convert it to the tensorflow shape **[filter_height, filter_width, in_dim, out_dim] or [3 3 64 128]**, to get the same results with a tensorflow model as with a caffe model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use `numpy` to resize the array to the dimension that you wish to transform it to. And then just pass it to `tensorflow` computation graph as usual.

For your case, you can use:

```
tf_array = caffe_array.reshape([3, 3, 64, 128])
```

Example:

```
In [1]: zer = np.array([[[ [1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 4]], [[5, 6, 6], 
                             [7, 8, 8]], [[0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1] ] ]])

In [2]: zer.shape
Out[2]: (1, 3, 2, 3)

In [3]: zer
Out[3]: 
array([[[[1, 2, 2],
         [3, 4, 4]],

        [[5, 6, 6],
         [7, 8, 8]],

        [[0, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1]]]])


In [4]: rez = zer.reshape([3, 2, 3, 1])

In [5]: rez.shape
Out[5]: (3, 2, 3, 1)

In [6]: rez
array([[[[1],
         [2],
         [2]],

        [[3],
         [4],
         [4]]],

       [[[5],
         [6],
         [6]],

        [[7],
         [8],
         [8]]],

       [[[0],
         [1],
         [1]],

        [[2],
         [1],
         [1]]]])
```